# NSNumber not being accurately set from NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nsnumber

In ViewControllerA, I am setting the following:

```
NSNumber *phaseIsKnownNSNum = 1

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:phaseIsKnownNSNum forKey:@"Phase is Known"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

In ViewControllerB, I'm able to pull this value from user defaults as long as I don't use the same "phaseIsKnownNSNum" variable name.  The following occurs after a button press in ViewControllerB:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

//using 2 instances of the standardUserDefaults, just to be sure.
NSUserDefaults *defaultsTest = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSNumber *testNum = [defaultsTest objectForKey:@"Phase is Known"];

NSLog(@"in ViewControllerB, btn pressed:  test %d", [testNum intValue]);
```

this logs "in ViewControllerB, btn pressed:  test 1".

```
NSNumber *testNum2 = [defaultsTest objectForKey:@"Phase is Known"];

NSLog(@"in ViewControllerB, btn pressed:  test2  %d", [testNum2 intValue]);
```

this logs "in ViewControllerB, btn pressed:  test2  1"

```
testNum = [defaults objectForKey:@"Phase is Known"];

NSLog(@"in ViewControllerB, btn pressed:  test %d", [testNum intValue]);
```

this logs "in ViewControllerB, btn pressed:  test 1"

when trying to use "phaseIsKnownNSNum" in ViewControllerB, I am not so lucky.

```
//I've tried not allocating & initializing.  Gives the same issue.
NSNumber *phaseIsKnownNSNum = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1];

NSLog(@"phaseIsKnownNSNum from initialized value:  %d", [phaseIsKnownNSNum intValue]);
```

this logs: "phaseIsKnownNSNum from initialized value:  1"

```
phaseIsKnownNSNum = [defaultsTest objectForKey:@"Phase Is Known"];

NSLog(@"phaseIsKnownNSNum from defaultsTest:  %d", [phaseIsKnownNSNum intValue]);
```

this logs "phaseIsKnownNSNum from defaultsTest:  0".

setting a breakpoint and inspecting the value of phaseIsKnownNSNum, it is nil.

```
phaseIsKnownNSNum = [defaults objectForKey:@"Phase Is Known"];

NSLog(@"phaseIsKnownNSNum from defaults:  %d", [phaseIsKnownNSNum intValue]);
```

this logs "phaseIsKnownNSNum from defaults:  0".

setting a breakpoint and inspecting the value of phaseIsKnownNSNum, it is still nil.

Is there some issue with reusing the same name for storing and retrieving user defaults?  I know the simple solution is to use a different variable name.  However, this default is retrieved in ViewControllers C, D, E, ...

It wouldn't make sense that the NSNumber variable name would have to be different each time.

Comment: `NSNumber *phaseIsKnownNSNum = 1` is obviously broken. You can't assign a plain `int` to an `NSNumber*` variable. Also, there's no semicolon. Show real code.

Comment: it should be `@1` probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start off using `@"Phase is Known"` with a lower-case `i`.  Then you switch to `@"Phase Is Known"` with an upper-case `I`.  This obviously doesn't match, so you don't retrieve the value that you saved.

You should save each NSUserDefaults key in a globally accessible constant somewhere, so that you don't make typos like this.